# theme_hook_suggestions and tpl.php

Tags: theming

```
if ($variables['node']->type == 'netrunner_card' && $variables['view_mode'] == 'full') 
{
    $blinksFileName = $variables['node']->field_card_type['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
    $blinksFileName = str_replace( " ", "_", $blinksFileName);
    $blinksTemplateName = 'node__netrunner_card__' . $blinksFileName . '__full';
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $blinksTemplateName;
}
```

I can't get the tpl to load! Ive got two tpl files currently for two types of cards.

'node--netrunner-card--Runner-Identity-Card--full.php'
'node--netrunner-card--Operation--full.php'

and I even tried:
'node--netrunner-card--Runner_Identity_Card--full.php'

Nothing. I'm so confused at this point I don't know where else to go...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please confirm your exact filenames for us.

Comment: quick issue is they should be foobarbazbing.**tpl**.php, eg, node--somethingorother.tpl.php not node--somethingorother.php

Comment: I am so ashamed... rookie move. Luckily, I'm still a Drupal rookie... thanks. tpl added, files working... D'oh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to rename my template files so that the extension was tpl.php instead of just .php. Once I renamed the files to add the tpl the files started working instantly.